# Why does won't my bitcoin transaction complete? It has thousands of confirmations

Tags: coinbase-transaction

[image]

My transaction has over 4000 confirmations and has been pending for over 3 weeks in my Coinbase wallet. The money is not available and shows as "pending". What is going on? If it had 0 confirmations I'd understand why but no one seems to have any information on this. I've reached out to coinbase multiple times but have only received the general answers that they have posted on their website for typical reasons that transactions are pending. This transaction that was sent to me has a decent fee attached. I don't know what to do. Has anyone seen something like this before? Here is the tx
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/60c0b24e664040dc8064b58c949de91d9550d4940ae51cf1eeaeab49f75e051a/

Comment: Coinbase is really not recommended wallet to use, Customer support service takes one month to respond and they never give access to your bitcoins, they handle the private keys.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction is indeed confirmed. You should double check to make sure you sent to the correct deposit address. If yes, then you will need to contact the Coinbase customer service to have your account balance updated properly.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is check that you have sent it to the right Bitcoin address. Your transaction is on the blockchain, the transaction is indeed confirmed on the blockchain, the funds are now only accessible to the owner of the private key of that address. Coinbase has a pretty bad support and is overwhelmed with tickets right now. I would recontact them with a very short and clear message.

- The transaction is confirmed but is not displayed on your Coinbase dashboard.
- You have already contacted them regarding this issue and they did not solve it.

Comment: This transaction was sent to me. I can see the transaction in my wallet, but shows as "Pending" and the bitcoin is not available. I have sent in about three tickets each about a week apart because they tend to send me the first response which gives me the typical pending issues and then do not respond again.

Comment: @johnnyb7184 What wallet software are you using? Also, please edit your question to include information about this. As is, it looks like it's CB who is refusing to credit you, while it seems this is an issue with your own wallet software.

Comment: How do I find which type of wallet software I am using?

Comment: Where did you download it? What name does it have? Does it have an "about" menu item? What platform is it running on (phone, desktop, which OS?)?